# Chromium repository for Debian

Tags: debian, chromium, repository, deb

I am in need of a Debian repository that serves more up-to-date versions of Chromium than the official Debian ones (last time I checked testing and unstable only had Chromium 21). Or not even that, maybe a site where daily .deb builds of Chromium are posted. I tried looking for this but can't find anything. I can't build from source as I lack the resources to do so.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You can try using the ubuntu source: `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntu/ precise main`

Comment: That looks outdated, seems like the last build was posted a few months ago.

Comment: do you need a repository to be used with apt? else you could manually download the .deb packages from google.